saber en que palets se encuentra una producto en Mongodb
tengo el siguiente problema
tengo el siguiente esquema (documentos) de base de datos en Mongodb
Documento de productos
productos: [
   {
      _id: objectId('jkhahsdkashdhkjashdkjasd'),
      código: 1234,
      descripción: 'Patas de cerdo'
   },
   {
      _id: objectId('ihsaiudhqwjbe87q38746238'),
      código: 5679,
      descripción: 'Lomo vetado'
   }
]

documentos de palet
palets: [
   {
      _id; objectId('jahsjdhakjsdhkajsdh'),
      cliente: objectId('io789374981274981479124'),
      idPalet: 190,
      productos: [
         {
            producto: objectId('jkhahsdkashdhkjashdkjasd'),
            fecha_E: 2024-11-10,
            fecha_V: 2025-11-09
            pesoTotal: 28.57,
            formato: 'cajas',
            unidades: 2
         },
         {
            producto: objectId('ihsaiudhqwjbe87q38746238'),
            fecha_E: 2024-11-10,
            fecha_V: 2025-11-09
            pesoTotal: 76,87,
            formato: 'cajas',
            unidades: 10
         }  
      ]
   },
   {
      _id; objectId('982734987239847324lkasjhfjkashf'),
      cliente: objectId('io789374981274981479124'),
      idPalet: 340,
      productos: [
         {
            producto: objectId('jkhahsdkashdhkjashdkjasd'),
            fecha_E: 2024-11-10,
            fecha_V: 2025-11-09
            pesoTotal: 28.57,
            formato: 'cajas',
            unidades: 2
         }
      ]
   }
]

Necesito saber en que pales se encuentra cada producto, estoy utilizando nodejs con mongoles
obtener una respuesta así
productos: [
   {
      producto: objectId('jkhahsdkashdhkjashdkjasd'),
      palets: [
         {
            palet: objectId('jkhahsdkashdhkjashdkjasd'),
         },
         {
            palet: objectId('982734987239847324lkasjhfjkashf'),
         }
      ]
   }
]

Agradecería mucho su ayuda, ya que llevo 1 mes tratando de hacer esto y he navegado por google tratando de buscar información al respecto
he tratado de usar aggregation pero no me ha resultado nada. (creo que no he sabido hacer bien la consulta)
muchas gracias
